# Does VS Code have a hotkey to flip an expression (eg. "a && b" to "b && a")?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hotkeys

In PHPStorm have feature who allows to fast flip expression.

I have:

```
if (a && b)
```

and carret between and when press Alt + Enter, PHPStorm proposes to flip operands to:

```
if (b && a)
```

Does have VSCode same built-in (without a plugin)?

Comment: Nope, without a Plugin you won‘t be able to do that. VS code improves, but this is none of its standards yet.

Comment: I've honestly *never* wanted that in an IDE. The reason why I don't want that is *order of evaluation matters* (in languages like C# and JS and..) and should not be idly transposed :} What am I missing?

Comment: @user2864740 this is exactly the reason for that feature to be desired, i often want to flip operands, because the reverse order is correct; now i have to do that manually, whereas in jetbrains  i was able to just invoke a quick action; isn't it a purpose of IDE — to make my life easier?